# From infinitesimal interval invariance to finite interval invariance in SR

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, inertial-frames, distance

In Landau and Lifshitz's The Classical Theory of Fields, on page 5 about interval invariance between different frames, it reads

> Thus, $$ds^2=ds'^2,\tag{2.6}$$ and from the equality of the infinitesimal intervals there follows the equality of finite intervals: $s=s'$.

However, it seems to me that one can deduce finite interval invariance from infinitesmal interval invariance only when the velocities of events in the two frames are constant. For, in that case, $$ds=\sqrt{c^2-v^2}dt=ds'=\sqrt{c^2-v'^2}dt'$$ where $\mathbb v$ and $\mathbb v'$ are constant. And then we can integrate to get $s=s'$. For the general case, in which $\mathbb v$ and $\mathbb v'$ are not constant, we cannot integrate to get the finite interval invariance. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The invariance of line elements is not limited to constant velocity. One can very well compute finite line elements for time-dependent velocity as:

$$s = \int_{t1}^{t2} dt \sqrt{c^2-v(t)^2}$$

in order to consider accelerated reference systems. This is useful if one wants to compute the length of a segment of a worldline which for instance spirals through space-time. In General Relativity this is studied and applied in more detail.